# UIImagePickerController hiding first UITableView cell on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

### Problem

It looks like either the `UITableView` insets/frame is wrong.
The first cell is partially hidden by the navigation controller.
Notice that I would like to avoid subclassing `UIImagePickerController` as Apple documentation states that:

> This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing

### Screenshot

[image: Image picker screenshot]

### Configuration

- OS: iOS 7.1
- Device: iPhone 4s (not simulator)

### Code

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[imagePicker setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:true completion:nil];
```

### Fix Attempts That Failed

1. I've tried to make sure that insets are automatically managed:
   `imagePicker.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;`
2. I've tried to verify that the VC is aware of the navigation bar:
   `imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = NO;`
3. The following fixes the issue but I'd like the navigation bar to remain translucent:
   `[imagePicker.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

This will happen with tableview, when you are scrolling tableview this is a normal behaviour. If you want it to properly align you can use the tableview method to do that

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:topRowValue inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

You will need to have the delegate of the tableview set to self and when the tableview has done scrolling, check which cell is on top and align it to the top using the above method. However, this will not guarantee the results as you desire. The reason for that is, you have different screen sizes for iphone4 and iphone5, say you have 5 cells that are visible in iphone5, in iphon4 it can happen that you see 4 cells completely and a part of the 5th cell in, as you are seeing now. So, if it isn't absolutely necessary, you can leave it as is.

Comment: Thing is I don't have access to the table view as it is encapsulated within the `UIImagePickerController` instance.

Comment: ok, so you can't see the first album? Its strange if that is the case. Let me try to see by running a sample code.

Comment: Working fine here with source type UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum

Answer (score 0):

self.tableview.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES; try this.

Comment: The tableview is not in my view controller, it is within the UIImagePickerController instance

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to this table view by conforming your class to protocol *UINavigationControllerDelegate*

```
extension YourController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard let photosTableView = viewController.view.subviews[0] as? UITableView else { return }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Storyboard as Follows...

1- Select your controller on storyboard

2- go to attribute inspector.

3- Uncheck "Adjust Scroll View view insets".